# How to convert Discord bot commands to hybrid command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to convert my Discord Bot commands to hybrid commands. When I don't use the hybrid_command decorator, the slash commands work.

The error says the callback must be a coroutine. What does it mean? What am I missing in the code?

main.py

```
class MyBot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self):
        intents=discord.Intents.all()
        intents.message_content = True

        super().__init__(
            command_prefix='!',
            intents=discord.Intents.all()
        )

        self.initial_extensions = [
            "cogs.user_commands"
        ]


    async def setup_hook(self):
        for ext in self.initial_extensions:
            await self.load_extension(ext)

        await bot.tree.sync(guild = discord.Object(id=191453821174531128))
```

user_commands.py

```
class user_commands(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        bot.remove_command("help")

    @commands.hybrid_command(name='help', with_app_command=True)
    @app_commands.command()
    async def help(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, command: Optional[str]):
        ......

        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral = True)

    @help.autocomplete('command')
    async def help_autocomplete(self,
        interaction: discord.Interaction,
        current: str,
    ) -> List[app_commands.Choice[str]]:
            .....
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: You probably want to remove that `app_commands.command()` line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, your error means that decorators `@commands.hybrid_command(...)` and `@app_commands.command()` do not go well together. You either define hybrid command, slash command or text-chat command.

Next moment, hybrid commands have `commands.Context` as their argument so we need to replace `interaction` parameter with that and adjust your `......` code accordingly -> replace usage of `interaction` with its analogical attributes/methods from `ctx` of said `commands.Context` class,

i.e. replace

- `interaction.user` with `ctx.author`
- `interaction.channel` with `ctx.channel`
- `interaction.response.send_message` with `ctx.send` or `ctx.reply`
- etc

So your code in `user_commands.py` would look like this.

```py
@commands.hybrid_command(name='help', with_app_command=True)
async def help(self, ctx: commands.Context, command: Optional[str]):
    ......

    await ctx.send(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)

@help.autocomplete('command')
async def help_autocomplete(self,
                            interaction: discord.Interaction,
                            current: str,
                            ) -> List[app_commands.Choice[str]]:
    .....
```

PS. it's not advisable to remove `help` command. I suggest reading this amazing github gist [A basic walkthrough guide on subclassing HelpCommand](https://gist.github.com/InterStella0/b78488fb28cadf279dfd3164b9f0cf96)

Comment: Thank you! the explanation was amazing.. Also for the help command, I didn't know about it!