# Discord.py and Heroku, @commands.slash_command(), how to fix?

Tags: heroku, discord, discord.py, web3py

```
# scripts/creation.py

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from role_selection import RoleSelectionView
from data import load_embed, save_data

class Creation(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.slash_command()
    async def embed_role_selection(self, ctx):
        """Create role embed"""
        dao_leader_role_id = 1158174122292035764
        if discord.utils.get(ctx.author.roles, id=dao_leader_role_id):
            await ctx.defer()

            embed = load_embed()
            view = RoleSelectionView()

            file1 = discord.File("images/ticketlogo.png", filename="ticketlogo.png")
            file2 = discord.File("images/ruff.jpg", filename="ruff.jpg")

            message = await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view, files=[file1, file2])

            save_data(message.channel.id, message.id)
        else:
            await ctx.send("You do not have the required role to use this command.", ephemeral=True)
```

```
# scripts/daobot.py

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from role_selection import RoleSelectionView
from creation import Creation
import moderation
from data import load_data
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
from monitoring import MonitoringCog
from verification import setup as setup_verification
import nft_command
import embed_generator

load_dotenv()
DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv('DAO_BOT_TOKEN')

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.presences = True
intents.guilds = True
intents.messages = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    data = load_data()
    if data:
        channel = bot.get_channel(data['channel_id'])
        if channel:
            try:
                message = await channel.fetch_message(data['message_id'])
                if message:
                    view = RoleSelectionView()
                    await message.edit(view=view)
            except discord.errors.NotFound:
                print(f"Message with ID {data['message_id']} not found in channel {channel.name}")

bot.add_cog(moderation.Moderation(bot))
creation_cog = Creation(bot)
bot.add_cog(MonitoringCog(bot))
setup_verification(bot)
nft_command.setup(bot)
embed_generator.setup(bot)

bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

```
2023-10-09T19:21:45.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ruffgreenw@gmail.com
2023-10-09T19:22:06.360496+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 7fc3ba6c by user ruffgreenw@gmail.com
2023-10-09T19:22:06.360496+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user ruffgreenw@gmail.com
2023-10-09T19:22:07.630260+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-10-09T19:22:09.500490+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python3 scripts/daobot.py`
2023-10-09T19:22:10.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2023-10-09T19:22:10.048828+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2023-10-09T19:22:11.141552+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-10-09T19:22:11.141584+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/scripts/daobot.py", line 6, in <module>
2023-10-09T19:22:11.141603+00:00 app[worker.1]: from creation import Creation
2023-10-09T19:22:11.141620+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/scripts/creation.py", line 8, in <module>
2023-10-09T19:22:11.141651+00:00 app[worker.1]: class Creation(commands.Cog):
2023-10-09T19:22:11.141652+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/scripts/creation.py", line 12, in Creation
2023-10-09T19:22:11.141679+00:00 app[worker.1]: @commands.slash_command()
2023-10-09T19:22:11.141711+00:00 app[worker.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-10-09T19:22:11.141780+00:00 app[worker.1]: AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'slash_command'
2023-10-09T19:22:11.309441+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2023-10-09T19:22:11.327178+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

I tried to use firstly @commands.slash_command(), because from local all works good even with flask.
When i tried to deploy to Heroku all discord bot repo, i started to swapping all @commands.slash_command() to @commands.command(), but this is not what i need.

I try to make bot with slash commands for dev, with some classic "!" commands, and web3 wallet verify ( like collab.land bot ).

So Heroku cannot find those @commands.slash_command(), can't imagine why xD.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in your code.

1. Defining both [discord.Client](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client) and [commands.Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#bot)

You should use only one, for the purpose of my following examples, I will use [commands.Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#bot).

2. `Bot.slash_command` does not exist.

Slash commands use [app_commands.command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.command).

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot) -> None:
        self.bot = bot

    @app_commands.command(name="mycommand")
    async def mycommand_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message(content="Hello world")

async def setup(bot: commands.Bot) -> None:
    await bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot))
```

And then in your main file:

```
from discord import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", ...)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.load_extension("mycog") #  Name of cog file
```

Read more in the documentation on [Cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html?) and [loading extensions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/extensions.html?).

3. Generally, you cannot use both slash commands and prefix commands.

Unless you use [hybrid commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.hybrid_command) ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72908362/how-to-convert-discord-bot-commands-to-hybrid-command)), or [on_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_message) event, you should only use either prefix commands or slash commands.